# Should require.js go at the top of the page or the bottom?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I know it's a typical best practice to put your scripts at the bottom of the page so they don't block other content from loading in. Require.js loads additional script tags asynchronously so I was wondering if it would be better to put it at the beginning or the end of your page. If you put it at the beginning you obviously have to wait for require to download but after that everything else should be async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rob, it's ok to put Require in the `<head>`. First of all, no, it won't wait until the page is loaded to start loading scripts - it will start loading them immediately. Secondly, it depends on your app, but some scripts that Require needs to load may need to be loaded immediately, not when HTML is loaded.

The issue you might run into, though, is how many simultaneous connections to the same domain browsers will support. If you have a lot of dependencies, you might want to looking into building bundles with [Require.js Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)